# Data not displayed in jQuery multiselect plugin

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to populate a drop-down using jQuery multiselect plugin. When I use simple drop-downs which have hard coded value, it works properly. However, when I fetch records from the database to populate a drop-down, the records are not displayed in the drop-down in IE (it works fine in Chrome).

JavaScript

```
<script>
function Fill(U, F, D, C) {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: U + '/' + F,
        data: D,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (r) {
            var i;
            //$('#' + C + '').length = 0;
            var myItem = r.d.split('#');
            $('#' + C + '').empty();
            for (i = 0; i < myItem.length; i = i + 2) {
                $('#' + C).append(new Option('' + myItem[i + 1] + '','' + myItem[i] + ''));
            }
        }
    });
}
 $(document).ready(function () {
                Fill('WebForm1.aspx', 'FillDepartmentDropdown', '{}', 'ddlDepartment');
                $("#ddlDepartment").multiselect({
                    header: "Choose an Department!"
                });
            });
</script>
```

cs

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string FillDepartmentDropdown()
        {
            string DataOutput = "";
            DataSet ds;
            Hashtable ObjParameters = new Hashtable();
            BusinessLogicLayer ObjBusiness = new BusinessLogicLayer();
            ds = ObjBusiness.SPDataSet(ObjParameters, "SelectAllDept");
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
                DataOutput = DataOutput + "#" + dr["Department"].ToString() + "#" + dr["id"].ToString();
            }
            return DataOutput;
        }
```

Html

```
<select id="ddlDepartment" ><option>32</option> <option>3213</option><option>321</option></select>
```

Comment: New Option sometimes works bad on IE, try change how you append it to '<option value="' + myItem[i + 1] + '">' + myItem[i + 1] + '</option>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `New Option` sometimes works bad on IE, try change how you append it to: `'<option value="' + myItem[i + 1] + '">' + myItem[i + 1] + '</option>'`

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery multiselect** plugin has a special method for adding options. Always look at **source code**, if API documentation is not clear enough:

```
$('#Portfolios').multiSelect('addOption', { 'value': value, 'text': text })
```

You can even use array of objects instead, providing several options at once.

Everything is very simple.

And no any refresh calls required, as some suggest.